# Django Token on test case return an error 'Authentication credentials were not provided'

Tags: django, unit-testing, token

I'm loggin inside the TestCase, creating another superuser for the test, but wen i send the token generated for this user, every call I send return me the error:

```
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Authentication credentials were not provided.', code='not_authenticated')}
```

I printed my headers:

```
{'Authorization': 'Token 5e4bd809ef42a4f17043a73eec10692382cd78d9'}
```

test.py

```
class CreditCardTestCase(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.user = User.objects.create_superuser(username='test.case',
                                                  email='test.case@gmail.com',
                                                  password='123456')

        if self.user is not None:

            try:

                self.token = Token.objects.get(user=self.user)

            except:

                self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.user)

            self.headers = {'Authorization': 'Token ' + self.token.key}

    def test_credit_card_with_invalid_number(self):

        print(self.headers)

        response = self.client.put('/api/v1/credit-card', {
            'exp_date': '02/2028',
            'holder': 'Olivia Johnson',
            'number': '1234567891231234',
            'cvv': '999'
        }, **self.headers)

        print(response.data)

        self.assertDictEqual({
            'message': 'Invalid Credit Card Number'
        }, response.data)
```

view.py

```
class CreditCardView(APIView):

    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, key):

        credit_card = CreditCardModel.objects.get(pk=key)

        serializer = CreditCardSerializer(credit_card)

        private_key = read_keys('private')

        serializer_data = serializer.data
        serializer_data['number'] = decrypt_credit_card_number(
            private_key, credit_card.number)

        return Response({
            'credit_card': serializer_data
        }, status=HTTP_200_OK)

    def put(self, request):

        try:

            params = request.data

            credit_card = CreditCard(params['number'])

            response = basic_info_verifier(params, credit_card)

            brand_obj = CreditCardBrand.objects.get(
                description__icontains=response['brand'])

            public_key = read_keys('public')

            print(public_key)

            encrypted_number = encrypt_credit_card_number(
                public_key, params['number'])

            credit_card = CreditCardModel(
                exp_date=response['expiration_date'],
                holder=params['holder'],
                number=encrypted_number,
                cvv=params['cvv'] if params['cvv'] else '',
                brand=brand_obj
            )

            credit_card.save()

            return Response({
                'message': 'Credit card registered with success',
                'card_id': credit_card.id
            }, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)

        except BrandNotFound:
            return Response({
                'message': 'Brand Not Found'
            }, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except InvalidCreditCardNumberException:
            return Response({
                'message': 'Invalid Credit Card Number'
            }, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except InvalidDateException:
            return Response({
                'message': 'Invalid Expiration Date, must be later than now and valid'
            }, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except InvalidHolderException:
            return Response({
                'message': 'Invalid Holder Name, must have at least 2 characters'
            }, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        except:
            return Response({
                'message': 'Error, code failed at card creation'
            }, status=HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Why the token are not working? if i use the same token on a postman call, in headers insert the same thing, it works.

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OEOz.png)

I tried to change from put to post, tried to call an function to login for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is the following:

```
response = self.client.put('/api/v1/credit-card', {
    'exp_date': '02/2028',
    'holder': 'Olivia Johnson',
    'number': '1234567891231234',
    'cvv': '999'
}, headers=self.headers)
```

When you pass `**self.headers` you basically are passing the following:

```
self.client.put('/api/v1/credit-card', {
    'exp_date': '02/2028',
    'holder': 'Olivia Johnson',
    'number': '1234567891231234',
    'cvv': '999'
}, Autorization=value)
```

And because normally most of the functions in python accept a `kwargs` it will just leave `headers=None` and that's why you are strugling with this...